# Android : Push Notification On click Going to main Activity

Tags: android, push-notification

Below is my Push Notication code. The problem is when i click Push notification it goes only to MainActivity instead of **PushNotificationActivity.java**

P.S : It works fine when the app is active.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushNotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_stat_exit)
                .setContentTitle("My First Project")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker("tickertexxxxtt")
                .setOngoing(true);


        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.title));
        bigTextStyle.bigText(messageBody);

        notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code of your  PushNotificationActivity.java?

Comment: In **PushNotificationActivity.java** i atttached a XML layout which has only Textview .

Comment: `public class PushNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.push_notification);
    }
}`